# login authentication control on button for PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, algorithm, authentication

Need to set a login control on a button for my wp website. Button's code appears to be like this:

```
$enable_redirect = get_field('redirect_to_offer') ? get_field('redirect_to_offer') : array('');

        echo'<a href="' . esc_url(get_field('url')) . '" target="_blank" class="btn btn-color btn-deal show-coupon-code" data-target="#discount-modal" data-clipboard-text="' . esc_attr(get_field('coupon_code')) . '" data-redirect="' . $enable_redirect[0] . '">' . fw_ssd_get_option('show-code-text') . '</a>';
    }
```

My goal is to check if the user who clicks on that button is logged in or not with:

```
if ( function_exists('um_profile_id') && !um_profile_id() && get_field('registered_members_only') ) {
wp_redirect(home_url('login/'));
exit;
}
```

But I couldn't figure out where should I put the controller code. F1 please.

Comment: Is `get_field( 'url' )` returning an internal or external URL?

Comment: It is returning an external URL.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest you not to show the button at all unless the user is logged in, or change the button URL based on the login status. Because the other solution could be an in-middle page that redirects the user accordingly based on the login status.

Comment: Changing button URL is actually a great idea. But how do I manage it in that code? Could you help me with that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your button URL is external, changing the button URL from the beginning seems to be a better option (as discussed on the comments):

```
$enable_redirect = get_field( 'redirect_to_offer' ) ? get_field('redirect_to_offer') : array( '' );

if ( function_exists( 'um_profile_id' ) && ! um_profile_id() && get_field( 'registered_members_only' ) ) {
    $button_url = home_url( 'login/' );
} else {
    $button_url = get_field( 'url' );
}

echo sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" target="_blank" class="btn btn-color btn-deal show-coupon-code" data-target="#discount-modal" data-clipboard-text="%2$s" data-redirect="%3$s">%4$s</a>'
    esc_url( $button_url ),
    esc_attr( get_field( 'coupon_code' ) ),
    esc_attr( $enable_redirect[0] ),
    fw_ssd_get_option( 'show-code-text' )
);
```

The login status defines the final button URL.

*Note: I used placeholder replacement with `sprintf()` in other to make it easier to read.*

Comment: Mitch, thanks a lot man! I would love to upvote your answer but I am a freaking newbie. Have a great year.

Comment: No prob! You can also [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem ;) have great year you too!